# Creating view using join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

```
CREATE VIEW tcs.meter_data_eb2 AS
select ar.created_date AS created_date,
p.id AS parameter_id,
p.parameter_name AS parameter_name,
ar.parameter_value AS parameter_value,
m.meter_primary_id AS meter_id,
m.meter_name AS meter_name
m.meter_code As meter_code
 from tcs.parameter_values_archieve ar
 inner join tcs.parameter_master p on p.id = ar.parameter_id
 inner join tcs.meter_primary_master m on m.meter_primary_id = ar.meter_id
 inner join tcs.meter_master mm on mm.meter_primary_id = m.meter_primary_id;
```

What is wrong with this query?

Its giving error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'm.meter_code As meter_code from tcs.parameter_values_archieve ar
>   inner join tc' at line 8

Comment: and what's the error message

Comment: @jw error message ...."You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm.meter_code As meter_code from tcs.parameter_values_archieve ar inner join tc' at line 8"

Answer (score 3):

you simply lack comma between `m.meter_name` and `m.meter_code`

```
, m.meter_name AS meter_name, m.meter_code AS meter_code
```

Full view query,

```
CREATE VIEW tcs.meter_data_eb2
AS
SELECT ar.created_date AS created_date , 
        p.id AS parameter_id , 
        p.parameter_name AS parameter_name , 
        ar.parameter_value AS parameter_value , 
        m.meter_primary_id AS meter_id , 
        m.meter_name AS meter_name,
        m.meter_code AS meter_code
FROM    tcs.parameter_values_archieve ar
        INNER JOIN tcs.parameter_master p
            ON p.id = ar.parameter_id
        INNER JOIN tcs.meter_primary_master m
            ON m.meter_primary_id = ar.meter_id
        INNER JOIN tcs.meter_master mm
            ON mm.meter_primary_id = m.meter_primary_id;
```